# Action bar text color

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I want to change the text color in my action bar. I tried a lot of things but can't change it. In the picture I want to change the word groups to white

This is my styles.xml file:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyCustomTheme.MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/MyEditTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyCustomTheme.MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/edit_text_text_size</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/app_font</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/edit_text_text_size</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyEditTextStyle" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/app_font</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/edit_text_text_size</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/app_font</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/edit_text_text_size</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is my actionbar:
http://pichoster.net/lPd

Comment: You want a white color?

Comment: @Alex Tech use try this code...     <style name="MyCustomTheme.MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/edit_text_text_size</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">@color/add_your_text_color</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
 int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
```

Now you can use the `ID` with a `TextView`

```
 TextView abTitle = (TextView) findViewById(titleId);
 abTitle.setTextColor(colorId);
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113280/discussion-between-dipali-shah-and-piyush-gupta).